# How would I count the number of people in each category BMI calculator

Tags: python

What do I need to do to count out each individual in each category. Underweight, normal weight, over weight and obese? The number of individuals in each category counted and the number in each of those categories displayed?

```
recipients = ["John", "Dee", "Aleister", "Lilith", "Paul", "Reggy"]
BMI_calc = []


def BMI(weights, heights):
    bmi_total = (weights * 703) / (heights ** 2)
    return bmi_total


def check(BMI):
  if BMI <= 18.5:
    print("Your underweight.")

  elif BMI > 18.5 and BMI < 24.9:
    print("You're normal weight.")

  elif BMI > 25 and BMI < 29.9:
    print("You're overweight.")

  elif BMI > 30:
    print("You're obese.")


for recipient in recipients:
    heights_ = int(input("What is your height " + recipient + "  :" ))
    weights_ = int(input("What is your weight " + recipient + "  :" ))
    BMI_info={"name":recipient,"weight":weights_,"height":heights_,"BMI":BMI(weights_, heights_)}
    BMI(BMI_info["weight"],BMI_info["height"])
    BMI_calc.append(BMI_info)



for person_info in BMI_calc:
    print(person_info["name"],end="\t")
    check(person_info["BMI"])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
overweight, underweight, normal, obese = 0

def check(BMI):
  if BMI <= 18.5:
    print("Your underweight.")
    underweight += 1
  elif BMI > 18.5 and BMI < 24.9:
    print("You're normal weight.")
    normal += 1

  elif BMI > 25 and BMI < 29.9:
    print("You're overweight.")
    overweight +=1

  elif BMI > 30:
    print("You're obese.")
    obese += 1
```

You can print or do anything you want to do with the count integer

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue as you which is how I came across your question(s). Instead of counting the normal way (ex. underweight += 1), I created lists for each category of BMIs. **I only used 3 categories**

```
OVER_LIST = []
UNDER_LIST = []
NORMAL_LIST = []
```

my function looked like this:

```
def your_function_name():
    if BMI > 30:
        OVER_LIST.append(BMI)
    elif BMI < 10:
        UNDER_LIST.append(BMI)
    else:
        NORMAL_LIST.append(BMI)
```

finally I called the function with each iteration of the for loop and simply printed the length of the lists:

```
for BMI in BMI_list:
    your_function_name()

print('Overweight = ',len(OVER_LIST),'\nUnderweight = ',len(UNDER_LIST),'\nNormal weight = ',len(NORMAL_LIST))
```